# Reference request: introduction to elliptic and parabolic obstacle problems

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, big-list

Where can I find introductory material, surveys, and lecture notes on various issues about elliptic and parabolic [obstacle problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstacle_problem)?

Comment: Good question.  I remember Evans mentions obstacle problems very briefly in Chapter 8 of his book Partial Differential Equations.  In the references, he suggests Friedman, Variational Principles and Free Boundary Problems and Kinderlehrer and Stampacchia, An Introduction to Variational Inequalities and Their Applications.

Comment: Maybe you can find something of your interest in the book by Rodriguez "obstacles problems"

Comment: The author's name is actually Rodrigues J. L.

Comment: @Dal Have you had any luck since in finding references, especially on the parabolic problem?